# Usar arquivos locais caso CDN esteja Offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn

Gostaria de saber se é possível realizar um callback caso uma CDN esteja offline o sistema use os arquivos locais.

Ex: Utilizo a CDN do Fontawesome mas caso o usuário fique sem internet ou a CDN fique offline, seja possível criar um callback para o sistema utilizar os arquivos locais.

Obs. O sistema deve dar preferencia para o uso da CDN caso ela esteja online e o usuário possua internet.

Comment: Por "arquivo local" você quer dizer "cache do navegador"?

Comment: Não, por exemplo, tenho a chamada da CDN e também a chamada dos arquivos locais <link src="fontawesome.min.css"> caso a CDN falhe o arquivo local é chamado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim. Vou dar um exemplo com o jQuery carregado na CDN do Google.

No `head` do seu HTML, você deve adicionar o script da CDN:

```
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

No `body`, adicione um código para verificar se o `$` foi definido, e caso não esteja, adicione o script "fallback" para ser carregado:

```
<script>
    if ( typeof $ === "undefined" ) {
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "//servidor.com.br/jquery-1.11.3.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
</script>
```

Só não se esqueça que se você possui scripts que necessitam do jQuery, eles devem ser carregados dinamicamente após o jQuery ser carregado, seguindo a mesma lógica acima.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, só não estava sabendo como fazer, sou iniciante em jQuery e já havia visto algo parecido em algum lugar, mas na época não dei bola. muito obrigado!