# Demo só funciona no JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, dialog, jsfiddle

Meu problema pode ser uma coisa bem simples, é que sou novo em programação de script e estou apanhando bastante! Não consigo fazer esta demonstração funcionar no meu arquivo.html:

[Link da demo no JSFidde: https://jsfiddle.net/h5q7pe3m/33/](https://jsfiddle.net/h5q7pe3m/33/)

coloco o seguinte no meu .html:

```
<div id="allow-or-not" title="Show Again?">
  <p>Would you like to show this dialog again?</p>
  <button name="yes" class="ok allowed">Yes</button>
  <button name="no" id="exit">No</button>
</div>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!localStorage.hideAlert) {
  $(function() {
    $("#allow-or-not").dialog();
  });
} else {
  $("#allow-or-not").css("display", "none");
}
$(".ok.allowed").on("click", function() {
  $("#allow-or-not").dialog("close");
});
$("#exit").on("click", function() {
  localStorage.setItem('hideAlert', true);
  $("#allow-or-not").dialog("close");
});
</script>
```

Tem algo que esteja faltando?

Comment: Não estão faltando as referências para o `jquery` no `head` da sua página? Se você olhar no resources do fiddle, vai ver que tem os links pro `jquery` e `jqueryui`

Comment: obrigado @RicardoPontual, nem tinha percebido que tinha essa parte de resources lá rss, agora fiquei ciente! (quiser add essa teu comentário como resposta posso marcar como certa)

Comment: adicionei como resposta, até se alguém já precisar dos links diretos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou adicionar as referências do `jquery`, que são feitas automaticamente no **JSFiddle** quando seleciona que vai usar `jquery`.

Só incluir no  `HEAD` os links:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Links copiados do *fiddle*, mas pode ser outras versões, de outro *CDN* ou ainda baixar e usar local.

Aqui uma pergunta relacionada, mostrando a tag completa: [Usar arquivos locais caso CDN esteja Offline](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63309/57220)